# jQuery validation not removing error upon valid email entry

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am trying to set up the jQuery validation plugin, to verify email address before sending. Which I have done many times before.

But just can't get it to work as expected for this new form. It doesn't stop the form submission, and it doesn't remove the error once the email address is valid.

I've included the stripped down code below and a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RFt/25/)

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" id="myform" method="post" name="myform">

    <label for="guest_email">What is your email address?</label>
    <input name="guest_email" placeholder="Email address" type="email"/>

    <button name="guest_submit" type="submit">Confirm</button>

</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            guest_email: {
                require: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I'm guessing this is glaringly obvious to someone but I just can't seem to find the answer.

The jQuery.validate.min.js is called from their CDN. As is /1.11.1/jQuery.min.js

There must be some conflict between the way I have set up the form, my JS and the plugin. I have the method working on a different page of my website.

Comment: you're getting this error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yhrd60c9/1/  i think your fiddle had a bug in it.

Comment: It can't be the fiddle, as its happening on my website too

Comment: Typo: `required` instead of `require`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Proper code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            guest_email1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle :)](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RFt/68/)

Finally I came to conclusion :) , you Should write `required`. U missed `d`

Comment: They are different, one is 'guest_email' one is 'guest_submit'

Comment: You updated your answer after I downvoted because your previous answer was wrong.

Comment: @Dijon , yes I look at the code in wrong manner , I updated it.

Comment: So what makes your code work? The submit handler change shouldn't be required for this to work

Comment: @Dijon , Hi I updated answer :) It was 15 mins long Searching the ISSUE :) .Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code works perfect in the jsfiddle. Anyway if it persists on your workstation, you can try to add this:

```
$('input[name=guest_email]').change(function ()
{
    $('input[name=guest_email]').valid();
}
```